# Export PNG in QGIS, same extent but outputs are not exactly the same

Tags: qgis, png

I export the PNG with same extent, same resolution and scale

[image][image]

but the output width are not exactly the same.

It's quite annoying to me, and I have no idea why could this happen

Are there any substitute solutions to export the map to PNG?

Below is the recording of steps I did

[image]

Comment: Try also layer-right click-Export-Save as...

Answer (score 2):

Try using a Print Layout. When you can create a map in a layout, you can specify it's dimensions by accessing it's properties (1). Pan the map location as desired, export as image (2), select PNG as your filetype, set output image resolution to your liking (3), and make sure you select "Crop to Content" before export (4).

[image: Layout map properties]

[image: Export options]